# How can i specify the field serialize order on Jackson

Tags: serialization, jackson

I have a class named Test extends another class named BasicTest, the class is like below:

```
public class Test extends BasicTest{
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

   // ... Getter and Setter
}

public class BasicTest{
    private String code;
    private Long time;

   // ... Getter and Setter
}
```

And i use jersey to provide RESTFul Api, here is the code of the endpoint:

```
@Path("/test")
public class MyEndpoint{
     @Get
     @Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Test myTest(){
          Test test = new Test();
          test.setName("Chris");
          test.setAge(29);
          test.setCode("200");
          test.setTime(100)
          return test;
     }
}
```

What i expect response is :

```
{
  "name": "Chris",
  "age": 28,
  "code": "200",
  "time": 100
}
```

But i got:

```
{
  "code":"200",
  "time":100,
  "name":"Chris",
  "age":28
}
```

My jackson object mapper provider configuration is:

```
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

public ObjectMapperProvider() {
    defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    return defaultObjectMapper;
}

private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
    //enable
    result.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    //disable
    result.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    result.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES);
    result.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    //include
    result.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    result.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);

    //Naming
    result.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

    return result;
}
```

}

Hope someone could help to check this, how can i get the response i expected, really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation to set property order while serialization as shown below.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name","age","code","time"})
public class Test extends BasicTest{
   private String name;
   private Integer age;

   // ... Getter and Setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the example which i do the test, for the real code i have a lot of classes to extend the BasicTest  class, i think using @JsonPropertyOrder on each class is not very graceful, any idea that i can do this more reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also use [@JsonProperty(index)](https://tedblob.com/jackson-serialization-order/) to control the order at the field level.

```
 public class Test extends BasicTest{
    @JsonProperty(index=1)
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(index=2)
    private Integer age;

   // ... Getter and Setter
}

public class BasicTest{
    @JsonProperty(index=3)
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty(index=4)
    private Long time;

   // ... Getter and Setter
}
```